# How to access RSS XML of wordpress

Tags: xml, wordpress, rss

I have to parse and fetch data from an RSS feed of Wordpress. Fetching XML into Android is not a problem, but when I am not logged into the site, the XML format of RSS is not shown and I can't parse it. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by clearing my browser's cache and its working :)